# How do you introduce yourself on the phone in a formal setting?

Tags: saludos, conversación-telefónica

We've had a [question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3800/9385) about identifying yourself when initiating a phone conversation, for an informal situation.

But what if you are making a formal call?  What if you address the other person formally, e.g. *don Roberto* or *Sr. Rodríguez*, and they call you *doña Alicia, Señorita Julia, Maestra Conchita,* or *Señora Álvarez*?

I know that it's best to begin with *Buenos Días* or *Buenas Tardes*.  But then what?

Please answer for both the case in which the person you want to talk to answers the phone, and also the case where a receptionist answers.

Answer (score 3):

This depends a lot on the culture, so, as they say, your mileage may vary. For me, using honorifics is mostly out of the question except for *señor* or *señora*. Using *señorita* for unmarried women is still heard of, and there's no suitable neutral replacement equivalent to English *Ms.* Female kindergarten and primary school teachers are customarily termed *señorita* but it's mostly by their pupils and their parents. I've never heard *don* or *doña* being used in formal calls.

I employ academic titles only in the most formal situations, mostly *doctor, arquitecto, ingeniero, profesor* and their feminine versions, only when I'm sure that the other person is normally addressed like that and/or insists on it. If not, *señor* and *señora*.

If I know the full name, I use it. This I find best if the other person has a very common surname like Pérez, García, López, etc.

I usually begin by saying *«Mi nombre es... y estoy llamando desde... Quería/Querría/Quisiera hablar con... ¿Se encuentra él/ella?»* or something like that. If I begin formally like that and the other person replies informally (i.e. by calling me by my first name), I tend to switch to the informal register immediately (but that's me and my usual kind of exchange).

If the person I want to talk to picks up the phone and I recognize their voice, I might simply say *«¿Hablo con...?»* to confirm. If not, I assume some receptionist or secretary is talking to me and proceed as above.

This all applies to calls from my office. I seldom call anyone formally for private purposes. When doing so, I guess I would be leaving out my own identification and just get to the point of asking for whoever it is I want to talk to, or simply state what it is that I want in a conventional polite register (*«Quisiera averiguar sobre...»* or *«Llamo para preguntar si sería posible...»* or the like).

Comment: Great start, thanks.  Now we need you to use your imagination and tell us how you would do it if you were the older or self-important person who does not introduce himself as Juanito, especially in situations where the two people already know each other.  I used to stumble over this when I was making business calls.  The relationship was solidly on *usted* footing, partly because the two parties were of opposite genders.  A weekly call was needed for business purposes.  I think it's easiest to use one's imagination to write authentic examples if you write a snippet of *dialogue*.  Thanks much.

Comment: To clarify, you want me to imagine that I'm an older/important person and I prefer to introduce myself formally even though I could afford not to do so, and also even though I personally know the other person. Right?

Comment: I got a little confused about the "afford not to do so."  Let me start over.  Imagine you are writing a screenplay.  There are two characters that have to call each other from time to time, sometimes one, sometimes the other.  They use *usted* with each other.  One is a woman and the other is a man.